# Cocoapods in subproject

Tags: cocoapods

I have a project with a subproject. Both the subproject and the main project must use Cocoapods to integrate a library which is seemingly impossible to integrate without Cocoapods. So I have Cocoapods set up for both the Main project and its subproject. The subproject builds in its generated workspace, but compiling the main project produces the following error: ld: library not found for -lPods-Subproject name-Library.

The only idea I have right now is that I should somehow get the subproject's Cocoapods repo to use the main project's name, so that when the subproject builds it will check for the same libraries as the main project's Cocoapods generates (presumably -lPods-Main Project Name-Library), which will have been created as part of the main project's build process.

How can I achieve this? Is there a better way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to write your podfile in that way:

```
workspace 'FinalWorkspace.xcworkspace'
xcodeproj 'MainWorkspace/MainWorkspace.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'SubWorkspace/SubWorkspace.xcodeproj'

target 'MainWorkspace' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'MainWorkspace/MainWorkspace.xcodeproj'
  pod 'nameofpod1', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'nameofpod2', '~> 2.2'
  pod 'nameofpod3', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'nameofpod4', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'SubWorkspace' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'SubWorkspace/SubWorkspace.xcodeproj'
  pod 'nameofpod3', '~> 3.3'
end
```

And then run FinalWorkspace.xcworkspace.

Comment: Do you have an example project hosted somewhere that could be used for reference?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have.

Comment: I did this, but i now have duplicate references to the nested project in my workspace.

Comment: @72A12F4E, There is an open issue : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7728

Comment: Builds fine, but iOS-unit-test crashs, like: "```dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyPod.framework/MyPod```" \n "```Referenced from: /private/var/Bundle/Application/.../MyTestHost.app/Frameworks/MySubProject.framework/MySubProject```" \n "```Reason: image not found```"

Comment: Solution; add `MyTestHost` into `Podfile` (without duplicating pods), and configure `inherit! :search_paths`