# Cocoapods for project and subproject

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to understand how to add dependencies to Xcode sub project with Cocoapods. 
My project structure is:

- Master project with some dependencies
- Subproject with some other dependencies (one  dependency is used by master and subproject).

I tried to use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394463/cocoapods-in-subproject) but it created another instance of the subproject in the workspace instead keeping it as subproject. 
Is it possible to work with Cocoapods with subproject? if do what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for Cocoapods v.1.0.0 and higher)

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
workspace 'YourWorkspace.xcworkspace'

platform :ios, '8.0'

project 'Project'
project 'Project/Subproject'

target 'ProjectTarget' do
  project 'Project'
  pod 'some-project-pod'
end

target 'SubprojectTarget' do
  project 'Project/Subproject'
  pod 'some-subproject-pod'
end
```